# Conditional density of transformation of Gaussian Random variable

Tags: probability

Suppose we know the conditional density of $X \vert Z$, where ($X,Z$) are jointly Gaussian, with $Z$ a non degenerate Gaussian random vector with $m$ components. Suppose $Z=AY$ where where ($X,Y$) are also jointly Gaussian,and $Y$ is a non degenerate Gaussian random vector with $n$ components, and $A$ is a $m$ by $n$ full rank, real valued matrix, with $m$  not equal to $n$.

The question is can we derive that the conditional density of $X \vert Y$  from the conditional density of $X \vert Z$.

The question came up when I was trying to adapt the proof of the conditional density of $X \vert Y$, where ($X,Y$) were jointly Gaussian real valued random variables to the multidimensional case.

If $A$ were invertible, I could use the Change of variable formula, but in this example $A$ is not invertible, though of full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. For a simple counterexample, assume that $n=1$, $m=2$, $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ is standard normal, $Z=Y_1-Y_2$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$ and standard normal. Thus the conditional density of $X$ conditionally on $Z$ is known and does not depend on $Z$.

But this happens if $X$ is independent of $Y$, and then the conditional density of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ is standard normal. Or, if $X=\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot (Y_1+Y_2)$, and then the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ is a Dirac mass. In both cases, the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is gaussian.

Or, more generally, this happens if $X=\frac{a}{\sqrt2}\cdot (Y_1+Y_2)+\sqrt{1-a^2}\cdot T$, where $|a|\lt1$ and $T$ is independent of $Y$, and then the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ is gaussian with mean $\frac{a}{\sqrt2}(Y_1+Y_2)$ and variance $1-a^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I get what you are saying. In the example you constructed, you showed that the conditional distribution of $X \vert Z$ was standard normal, but the conditional density of $X \vert Y$ could be standard normal or even a Dirac mass - which is to say the conditional density of $X \vert Z$ does not always specify the conditional distribution of $X \vert Y$.